# Deploying desktop app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, deployment, desktop-application

I create wpf desktop application with sql server 2008 database?

The database is stored on Sqlexpress in my local machine.

Could any one tell how could I deploy the database on the client machine ?

The database should be use locally on one user only machine

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database files (data/log) are currently attached to your database server all you have to do is to deattach and pack them within your application setup (using your setup project properties, settings, etc.). Your setup program should be intelligent enough to detect if there is any sqlexpress instance present on the target computer if none then install a fresh instance of sqlexpress and either attach the files to the instance using a script or just using your connection string to force a dynamic instance to attach them for you when the application is in use.

Comment: Could you provide me with example or good link that describe the process?

Comment: A "dynamic instance" is well known as a "user instance" here is an article from microsoft that explain the process and how to create the connection strings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564(v=sql.90).aspx . On the other hand, including the database files in your proyect should not be so difficult just add a new setup project to your visual studio solution (if you have not done so) and play with the properties (adding additional files, required packages [this in case you need your setup to install sqlexpress], etc).

Comment: Here is another article from microsoft that explain how to create setup and deployment packages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzawcsz(v=vs.80).aspx. If you need further assistance just let me know.

Comment: I forgot to mention the links are for visual studio 2005 but they should give you a good idea of how to get everything done in visual studio 2010.